# Putting if statements inside php function with parameters?

Tags: php

Im trying to put these if statements inside a php function to get results. So far its not working. I know this may be an easy solution, but I am new to PHP and the other examples that I looked at didnt help me a lot.
**FUNCTION**

```
$startdate='';
$enddate='12/3/2020';

function startEnd($startdate,$enddate){
    if($startdate==''){
        $startdate='Anytime';
    }
    if($enddate==''){
        $enddate='Anytime';
    }
}
```

**CALL**

```
startEnd($startdate,$enddate);

echo $startdate;
echo $enddate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use variables that are outside of the scope of the function.

Once it is passed as an argument, in the function, it will be treated as a completely new variable. Unless you reintroduce them to the scope with `global`.

You can, however, pass a *reference* of a variable to a function using the `&` operator in the parameters.

```php
function startEnd(&$string1, &$string2) {
    if ($string1 === '') {
        $string1 = 'Anytime';
    }
    if ($string2 === '') {
        $string2 = 'Anytime';
    }
}
startEnd($startdate, $enddate);
```

Comment: all i did was literally add an `&` to the front of each variable in the function and it worked now. didnt have to change anything else. it works exactly the same as javascript, i just didnt know how to pass it i guess, thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3783243 I am aware but the use of `global` is discouraged for many reasons.

Comment: @user3783243 I upvoted your comment for the suggestion and edited my answer.